# Get a list of files in a directory with a specified pattern in filename in VB 6

Tags: vb6

I have a directory and it contains a number of files, 
Some filenames start with say, `abc_001.ini, abc_002.ini, abc_003.ini` and so on.
There are other files as well in the same folder.
I want to get a list of files which start with **abc_** and have a **".ini"** extension.
How can I do this in **VB 6**?

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly stolen from the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262727(v=vs.60).aspx

```
MyPath = "c:\wherever\abc_*.ini"   ' Set the path.
MyName = Dir(MyPath, vbDirectory)   ' Retrieve the first entry.
Do While MyName <> ""   ' Start the loop.
   ' Ignore the current directory and the encompassing directory.
   If MyName <> "." And MyName <> ".." Then
      Debug.Print MyName 
   End If
   MyName = Dir   ' Get next entry.
Loop
```